# read specific lines from a file using python

Tags: python

I have a file with data like:

```
   1xxy
   (1gmh)

[white line]
ahdkfkbbmhkkkkkyllllkkjdttyshhaggdtdyrrrutituy
[white line]  
   __________________________________________________
   Intra Chain:
   A 32
   __________________________________________________
   PAIR 1MNS HE 10 NM A ARG 33 OX1 3.22 32
   PAIR 1MNS UR 11 NM A ARG 33 OX2 3.21 12
   PAIR IMNS UK 32 NH A ASN 43 OZ1 5.21 22
   ...
   __________________________________________________
```

NOW i want to make it like:

```
   PAIR 1MNS HE 10 NM A ARG 33 OX1 3.22 32
   PAIR 1MNS UR 11 NM A ARG 33 OX2 3.21 12
   PAIR IMNS UK 32 NH A ASN 43 OZ1 5.21 22
   ...
```

i.e. remove all other characters.
i tried using:

```
inp = open('c:/users/rox/desktop/1UMG.out','r')
for line in inp:
    if not line.strip():      # to remove excess whit lines
       continue
    else:
       z = line.strip().replace('\t',' ')
       if z.startswith('PAIR'):
          print z
inp.close()
```

but this code is also giving me no output. Can't figure out why `z.startswith('PAIR')` is not working. But up to the previous line it is going fine.

Comment: Regular Expression check out [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Comment: `(r' filename.txt').read()` actually works?

Comment: @joel it does fine for me. it is (r'filename.txt').read().....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are looking only at lines that start with `PAIR`, so why not something simple like this:

```
with open('data.txt') as infp:
   for line in infp:
      line = line.strip()
      if line.startswith('PAIR'):
         print(line)
```

will give:

```
PAIR 1MNS HE 10 NM A ARG 33 OX1 3.22 32
PAIR 1MNS UR 11 NM A ARG 33 OX2 3.21 12
PAIR IMNS UK 32 NH A ASN 43 OZ1 5.21 22
```

This output removes the leading 3 spaces, it would be trivial to add them back in if needed.

*Note*: using`with` will automatically close the file for you when you are done, or an exception is encountered.

Comment: "not working" isn't enough information to work with.  What happens?  What is the resulting output?  Is an exception raised?  Etc.

Comment: whats the size of the file.If its big it may take a while to process and print the output

Comment: @Ovisek: do you see how @Levon opens the file using the `with` line?  That's like `infp = open('data.txt')` but it automatically closes `infp` when the block ends.  In your code, however, you never open any file, you simply iterate over the filename `inp = ('c:/users/rox/desktop/1UMG.out')` itself.  You're iterating over the characters in the string, not the lines in the file.  (You also changed the code so you don't strip `z`, so if there are spaces before PAIR it will fail, but that might not be a problem in practice.)

Comment: @Ovisek: you **need to open a file**.  `inp = ('c:/users/rox/desktop/1UMG.out','r')` makes inp into a tuple of two strings, `'c:/users/rox/desktop/1UMG.out'` and `'r'`.  So `for line in inp` then iterates over those two strings, neither of which starts with PAIR.  If for some reason you don't want to use the `with` line, then write `inp = open('c:/users/rox/desktop/1UMG.out','r')` and add an `inp.close()` at the end.

Comment: yeah! sorry that was my mistake during typing here. but i actually used those during compiling my code. but still no output..

Comment: As I said, you changed Levon's code so that he strips the line before he uses `.startswith()` but you don't, so if there are any leading spaces, his code will work and yours won't.  Add a 'print line` in your second branch -- i.e. after the else -- to make sure that the lines are actually being read, and you'll probably see spaces at the start.  [Incidentally, did you ever try Levon's code as he wrote it?  Because it should work.]

Comment: i have tried Levon's code. but it failed. And in my code I took: 'print z' just before 'startswith()' line and whatever I got in output there was no leading spaces confirmed.that means I am having problem with the 'startswith()' line.Is there any other way to do it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12330/discussion-between-ovisek-and-dsm)

Comment: @Ovisek Can you tell me **what exactly didn't work** when you tried my code? I cut-and-pasted it directly out of the interpreter (v2.7.2). For 3.2.3 you only need to change `print line` to `print(line)`, but the code generated the output I showed, so this is very puzzling (in fact I just ran it again). What do you have in your data file? I copied what you showed in your post into a file named `data.txt` and used that. Can you try that? This makes me wonder if there's different data being processed. (Thanks @DSM for fielding questions .. did you resolve this in chat?)

Comment: @Ovisek if you really don't want to use `startswith` you can substitute this line (not as nice, but also tested and works): `if line != '' and line.split()[0] == 'PAIR':` in place of the previous if-statement that used `startswith`. Without any additional information though I suspect the problem lies with your data file. Can you read and print out the file w/o any processing?

Comment: @Levon: no, I gave up and went to sleep.  Was probably something simple, but it's been accepted now so maybe the OP found the problem..

Comment: @levon this code works good for me now.. I had a formatting issue...totally resolved.. +1 for helping me so much...thanx...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Levon's explanation, since the file object supports the iterator protocol, and depending on the size of the file, a list comprehension can be used:

```
[l for l in open('test.txt') if l.startswith('PAIR')]
```

Comment: @Ovisek: Wrong, it works fine. Learn at least the basics of Python before such statements of yours.

Comment: but it's not working with me. if you think itz my basics prob, then please give me a hint.

Comment: you need to handle the leading blanks for this to catch the lines starting with 'PAIR', ie l.strip().startswith('PAIR')

Comment: .. and you'd have to also take care of stripping the trailing `\n` (I'm a big fan of list comprehension too by the way)